# OSX Yosemite: Terminal "installer" won't start pkg file

Tags: macos, terminal, installation, osx-yosemite

So I am a TA for a class and I am trying to update my script for OSX Yosemite. It installs 3rd party USB drivers for the Arduino Nano. My problem is that the script no longer opens the .pkg file to install the drivers, and I can't figure out why. The line in my script is:

```
sudo installer -pkg "FILEPATH/HERE.pkg" -target /
```

This is the output it gives, but the installer doesn't actually open:

```
installer: Package name is ch34xInstall
installer: Upgrading at base path /
installer: The upgrade was successful.
installer: The install requires restarting now.
```

I went to go look in / in Terminal and a file named "installer.failurerequests" showed up with these contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
            <key>Operation</key>
            <string>fsck target</string>
            <key>CrashAtProgress</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Anyone have an idea what's going on here?

Comment: What is installer.failurerequests in the root directory? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229604/what-is-installer-failurerequests-in-the-root-directory